# on a mongo query, what does it mean to have a $gt or $lt on an undefined?

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

how can a logic comparitor like $lt be applied on an undefined value?  is undefined a number?  Here is an example:

```
$lt: ['$property', undefined]
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this question, `undefined` or missing fields are treated as `null` in mongo. `null` is considered as less than any numeric value. So the operator "$lt" on an undefined field will always return `true`. While the operator "$gt" on an undefined field will always return `false`.